# FizzBuzz list comprehension

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I was messing around with some different fizz buzz scripts as I learn python. I came across this one which works great but I can't decipher how it works. I know how the normal fizz buzz works with a for loop and "if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0". What has me stumped is how *"Fizz"*(*not i%3*) + "*Buzz*"*(not i%5)"* works.

```
x = ["Fizz"*(not i%3) + "Buzz"*(not i%5) or i for i in range(1, 100)]
```

Comment: You could try to evaluate the parts independently for small `i` in an interactive Python session: `"Fizz"*(not 10%3)` or `"Buzz"*(not 5%5)`.

Comment: In Python the * operator on a string allows one to "multiply" a string by a positive integer ... that is to specify a number of times to repeat the string.  So "somestring" * 0 means don't repeat it at all; replace it with an empty string.  Thus this clever list comprehension generates a list of "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz" strings, or integers, based on the boolean coercion on the numeric results of various modulo (mathematical remainder) operations on each of the numbers in the range 1 through 100).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python you can replicate a string by using the multiplication operator:

```
print('aaa' * 3) # aaaaaaaaa
```

Also, boolean values are implicitly casted to integers on multiplication. Thus, if you do

```
"Fizz"*(not i%3)
```

First, the i%3 will return the result of the modulo. Then, the `not` operator will convert it to either `True` if the result was 0, or to `False` otherwise (by casting it to boolean and then negating the value). By then applying a multiplication operator, `False` turns to 0 and `True` turns into 1.

Thus, if the number is divisible by 3, we get 0 as the result of the modulo, `True` when applying `not`, 1 when multiplying, and the string `Fizz` replicated 1 time as the result of the multiplication. If it is not divisible, we get 0 as operand for the multiplication, effectively getting the string `Fizz` replicated 0 times, thus an empty string.

The same goes for `Buzz`, and the result for each `i` in the range is just the concatenation of the two.

Comment: Thank you, martinarroyo, I guess I knew that False is 0 and True is 1, just didn't put them together with the implicitly casted to integers on multiplication. Thanks for the well written answer.

Comment: Thank you. It is a very ingenious way of working with value casting :D

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension is expressed as

```
  L = [mapping-expression for element in source-list if filter-expression]
```

now, replace "for element in source-list" part with

```
 for i in range(1, 100)
```

which iterates over a list of containing integers 1 to 99 returning one integer at a time.

"mapping-expression" here is

```
 "Fizz"*(not i%3) + "Buzz"*(not i%5) or i
```

which uses the integer i returned from "for i in range(1, 100)"

when i is divisible by 3 or 5, i % 3 and i % 5 returns 0, any other integer retuned when i is not divisible.

```
  (not i % 3) # return True when i is divisible by 3
  (not i % 5) # returns False when i is not divisible by 5
```

when the booleans returned from (not i % 3) or (not i % 5) is multiplied with strings "Fizz" and "Buzz":

```
  "Fizz" * True   # returns "Fizz"
  "Buzz" * False   # returns ""
```

then the Strings returned above are concatenated

```
   "Fizz" + ""
```

as a result "Fizz" is placed in the resulting list and this process goes on for each iteration, returning either "Fizz" or "Buzz" or sometimes times the integer i itself when both the string boolean multiplication returns a empty string "". since

```
     "" + "" or i    # returns i
```

The resulting list is something like  [1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 7, 8, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 11, 'Fizz', 13, 14, 'FizzBuzz' ......]

note : the optional "if filter-expression" is not used in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
["Fizzbuzz" if (i%3 == 0 and i %5 == 0) else "Fizz" if (i%3 == 0) else "Buzz" if (i%5 == 0) else i for i in x]
```

Hope this clears.

Comment: You can also use i%15 == 0 for "FizzBuzz" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 3%3
0
>>> not 3%3
True
>>> 
>>> 3%2
1
>>> not 3%2
False
>>> 
>>> if 0:
...   print 'true'
... 
>>> if 1:
...   print 'true'
... 
true
>>> False * 'Fizz'
''
>>> True * 'Fizz'
'Fizz'
```

You can see that `3%3` evaluates to `0` and `0` evaluates to False.  `1` evaluates to true.

In the comprehension, it loops for every number from 1 to 99, and if `i%3` evaluates to `True` or `i=3; 3%3`, then `"Fizz"` is printed and the same is true for `"Buzz"` if `i%5 == 0`.

If neither `"Fizz"` nor `"Buzz"` get printed, the part before the `or` here: `"Fizz"*(not i%3) + "Buzz"*(not i%5) or i` evaluates to `''+''` so the `or` part of the condition is printed, which is just `i`.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, the `%` operator returns the remainder of a given dividend and divisor. This operation only returns `0` when the operation returns no remainder.

For example, if `i % 3 == 0`, then `3` is a factor of `i`. Therefore `i % 3 and i % 5` will only return `0` when `3` or `5` can divide `i`.

Thus `not i % 3` will only return `1` if `i` is divisible by `3`. The `not` statement inverts the output, where a nonzero remainder (`true`) becomes the 0 value (`false`). Likewise, a zero remainder will become the value `1` (`true`).

When a string like `"Fizz"` is multiplied with a `0`, it will become the empty string. When multiplied with a `1`, it will remain the same. I believe this is due to the numerical representation of strings but someone can correct me if this is not the case.

Therefore, `"Fizz"` and/or `"Buzz"` will only exist in the output of that expression if `i % 3` and/or `i % 5` return `0` remainders. Meaning that `i` is divisible by `3` and/or `5`.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite:

```
#!python
from __future__ import print_function
def fizz_buzz(lower=1, upper=101):
    return ["Fizz"*(x % 3 == 0) + "Buzz"*(x % 5 == 0) or str(x) \
       for x in range(lower, upper)]

print('\n'.join(fizz_buzz()))
```

All the action is in a list comprehension expression and most of that is in conditional expression which either evaluates into a string ("Fizz", or "Buzz" or "Fizz"+"Buzz") or into a string representation of the integer being evaluated.

This relies on Python's relatively unusual (perhaps even obscure) * operator for strings ... to "multiply" a string via duplications and concatenation ... and also on Python's semantics regarding evaluation of "truth."  (In Python empty sequences: strings, lists, and tuples, as well as other empty containers, dictionaries and sets, and numerically zero values are all "false" --- along with the special *None* and *False* objects).

Back to your question.  Python treats "multiplying a string by zero" as an empty string.  It also treats a Boolean object as 1 or 0 in any arithmetic context (such as multiplication).  Thus the Boolean of *not i%3* is *True* if the object is divisible by 3 ... that is the modulo 3 operation returns a non-zero value.  So each of these strings is "multiplied" by one or zero (the equivalent of calling *int(not(bool(i%X)))* ... where X is 3 in one subexpression and 5 in the other.  (Note: *not* is a unary operator, not a function; but it can be written like a function call because *not(x)* evaluates the same as *not x* ... the extraneous parentheses are harmless in most cases).

I prefer returning (or yielding) the string conversion of the integer precisely because you can then uses the results from this expression in other functions in a natural way (for example when calling the *string.**join()*** method).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach helps me understanding the list comprehension structure.

```
def fizzBuzz(upper_limit):

  def mapper(a):
    result = ''
    if a % 3 == 0:
      result = result + 'Fizz'
    if a % 5 == 0:
      result = result + 'Buzz' 
    return result

  return [mapper(x) if mapper(x) else x for x in range(1,upper_limit+1)]

fizzBuzz(16)
[1,2,'Fizz',4,'Buzz','Fizz',7,8,'Fizz','Buzz', 11,'Fizz',13,14,'FizzBuzz',16]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
def fizz_buzz(upper):
    up_limit = upper +1
    fbl = ['fb' if i%15 == 0  #fizzbuzz if divisible by both
       else 'f' if i%3 == 0   #fizz if divisible by 3
       else 'b' if i%5 == 0   #buzz if divisible by 5
       else i                 #else present number
       for i in range(1,up_limit)]
    return fbl
```