# Using if, elif and else in list comprehension in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to convert a loop-based script containing `if`, `elif` and `else` into a list comprehension but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Here is the script I wrote (it prints the numbers from 1 to 100, but for multiples of 3 it prints 'fizz', for multiples of 5 it prints 'buzz' and for multiples of both 3 and 5 it prints 'fizzbuzz'):

```py
for num in range(1, 101):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
        print('fizzbuzz')
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        print('fizz')
    elif num % 5 ==0:
        print('buzz')
    else:
        print(num)
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What does this have to do with list comprehensions?

Comment: @Sayse I guess they want to re-factor their `for` loop as a comprehension, but it's not clear

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41077697/1324033)

Comment: The question is to reduce the lines of code using list comprehension

Comment: You shouldn't (ab)use list comprehensions here, because they're for quick one-off data transform/filter operations. Don't try to fit complex logic inside comprehensions. What you have here is just fine

Comment: You cannot use elif in comprehension lists but you can use if/else expression : `[(1 if x % 2 == 0 else 0) for x in range(100)]`

Comment: You should reperate IO (this is what printing is) from logic. So what do you want? You want to have a list with numbers and `"fizzbuzz"` at certain places. Never use list comprehension to do IO.

Comment: Did you tried [`elif` in list comprehension conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9987483/6194097) question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elif` is not part of the *if-else short-hand*, aka [if else conditional operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/ternary.html#if-else-conditional-operator), but you can achieve the same logic by chaining these operators, for example:

```py
if A:
    v = a
elif B:
    v = b
else:
    v = c
```

turns into

```py
v = a if A else b if B else c
```

And you can use a conditional operator expression in your list comprehension:

```py
[a if A else b if B else c for something in someiterator]
```

---

Note that things can become unreadable quite quickly, for example this may not be recommended in your example:

```py
['fizzbuzz' if num%3 == 0 and num%5 == 0  else 'fizz' if num%3 == 0 else 'buzz' if num%5 == 0 else num for num in range(1, 101)]
```

Comment: You should NOT use list comprehension unless you plan to use the resulting list.  List comprehension is not just a way to do a one line for loop.  At bare minimum two line it with a generator. If you want it in one line than just use `;` though the OP should break out of the mentality that one line of code is better than multiple.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is not the right tool since you want to *do something*
(`print`) and not to *produce a list*.

First, you should replace the "switch" by a function:

```
def foobar(num):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
        return 'fizzbuzz'
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        return 'fizz'
    elif num % 5 ==0:
        return 'buzz'
    else:
        return str(num) # return a string to have a consistent return type
```

(You can make a one liner of this function as in @EnzoBnl's answer if you want, but that's not a good idea.). Now, you code looks like:

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    print(foobar(num))
```

If you want a list comprehension (a generator here), use:

```
print("\n".join(foobar(num) for num in range(1, 101)))
```